# there is a function that can do a match between strings in R?

Tags: r

I am asking about a function that allows to do easily something like

```
grepl(c("word1","word2"), vector_of_strings)
```

I mean, doing something like: "There is these words in some position of this vector?" `TRUE/FALSE`

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly clear what you want. Do you want the index?

Comment: Look at `?match`

Comment: Please provide example input and expected output.

Comment: Why are you rating me negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like `stringr::str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
strings <- LETTERS[1:2]
# "A" "B"
lookin <- c("ALPHABET", "DOG")
str_detect(lookin, strings)
# TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
vector_of_strings <- c(
    'here is word1',
    'and word2 plus word4',
    'but word3 and word1 are here'
)

sapply(c("word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"), function(x){
    grepl(x, vector_of_strings)
})

##      word1 word2 word3 word4
## [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
## [3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

where each row of the returned matrix corresponds to an element in the vector of strings.

Comment: your answer is good, but there is a better, thank you